# How to use a image picker in table view controller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.codingexplorer.com/choosing-images-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift/) to create a image picker which is accessed from a UITableViewController. However it fails to compile in this line:

```
imagePicker.delegate = self
```

With this error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'ProfileTableViewController' to type 'protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>?'
```

How do I solve this? My class:

```
class ProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
      imagePicker.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Where is your UINavigationControllerDelegate, you need to inherit it.

Comment: just add **UINavigationControllerDelegate** after **UIImagePickerControllerDelegate** in your viewcontroller

Comment: This is not the whole code, there are some code to create  the UITableView. But what does a UINavigationControllerDelegate looks like? I dont have something like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034987/setting-delegate-for-uiimagepicker-returns-error-swift

Comment: It seems to work but I dont understand why. I didn't needed a UINavigationControllerDelegate before. So why do I need it after implementing image picker?

Comment: when you click the button from current viewcontroller to navigate the imageController so we need "UINavigationControllerDelegate" delegate. "UIImagePickerControllerDelegate" which is used to access the selection and failure response through @jacob smit

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a UINavigationControllerDelegate to the class fixed the issue.